# Getting the Azure service properties errors on dev environment

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I would like to set the DefaultServiceVersion for my azure storage instance, so I wrote the following code:

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("CloudStorageConnectionString"));

CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var serviceProperties = blobClient.GetServiceProperties();
if (serviceProperties.DefaultServiceVersion != "2011-08-18")
{
    serviceProperties.DefaultServiceVersion = "2011-08-18";
    blobClient.SetServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
}
```

I then tried to run it with the development storage server, and got an exception (erroring in the dev server by the looks) from `blobClient.GetServiceProperties()`

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.StorageServerException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Server encountered an internal error. Please try again after some time.
  Source=Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TaskImplHelper.ExecuteImplWithRetry[T](Func`2 impl, RetryPolicy policy)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobClient.GetServiceProperties()
       at ConsoleApp.GetContainer() in c:\app\Program.cs:line 90
       at ConsoleApp.Main() in c:\app\Program.cs:line 47
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
            at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.EventHelper.ProcessWebResponse(WebRequest req, IAsyncResult asyncResult, EventHandler`1 handler, Object sender)
       InnerException:
```

Is it possible to set the DefualtServiceVersion with a dev server? I haven't tried with the real thing as I really only want to test if this solves another issue I'm having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.getserviceproperties.aspx (scroll down to "Remarks" section), this operation is not currently supported on local storage. Also `SetServiceProperties` operation which enables/disables storage analytics is also not supported.